# Startup Sequence of Nodejs Apps using PM2

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, pm2

I am using the command `pm2 start apps.json` to start multiple apps in a single command. These apps are defined in `apps.json`:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "script": "./foo.js",
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "script": "./bar.js",
    },
    {
      "name": "baz",
      "script": "./baz.js",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Question:** Is it possible to define the startup sequence, such that `foo.js` has to finish starting first before `bar.js` and `baz.js` can start?

For example, `foo.js` can [perform a graceful start](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#graceful-start), running `process.send('ready')` to change its pm2 status to `online`. Only then will `bar.js` and `baz.js` be started by pm2. This will be similar to Docker Compose's `depend_on` parameter.

Comment: there are some questions that affects possible approaches: 1. are their startup sequence sync. or async.; 2. do they expose any ports; 3. are they singleton, i.e. is it safe to assume only 1 of each will be running on a single system.

Answer (score 3):

No such thing can be done via the configuration file only, but PM2 has a [programmatic api](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/#programmatic-api) which allows you to perform *IPC* (Inter-Process communication).

The following methods are the ones to work with :

- `pm2.list` To list the processes that are running and get their names / IDs
- `pm2.launchBus` For the processes that will **receive** information and react in consequence
- `pm2.sendDataToProcessId` For **sending** informations to another process

This way you can run multiple scripts and make one wait for another. Once a script recieve a message on the *message bus*, it can start a process with `pm2.start`

Here's a piece of **PSEUDO-CODE** to illustrate my point :

```
const pm2 = require('pm2');

pm2.connect(() => {
  pm2.list(function(err, processes) {
    const fooProcess = processes.find(p => p.name == 'foo');

    pm2.launchBus((err, bus) => {
      bus.on('process:msg', packet => {
        if (packet.startBar === true) {
          pm.start({ script: 'bar.js' }, (err, apps) => { ... })
        }
      });
      bus.on('error', console.error);
    });
  });
});
```

In another script, you would have the following :

```
pm2.sendDataToProcessId(barProcessID, {
  data : { startBar : true },
  topic: 'process:msg'
}, (err, res) => console.log(err, res));
```

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

A little hack, you can write: `"start": "pm2 start server.js && pm2 start server1.js"` inside `package.json`. If you'd run it as npm start, it'll run the start script, similarly, you can create the script to stop it.

If not then you can also use `child_process` [it comes by default with nodejs] to run commands from inside your script by using `childProcess.exec('pm2 start server.js && pm2 start server1.js');`